# Windows Mobile 6.5 device disables wireless when docked

Tags: windows-mobile, wireless, docking

I have a new Motorola MC75A which I have configured and am trying to debug some code but how do you stop the wireless NIC disabling when the Windows Mobile 6.5 device is docked?

Thanks

Phil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'r using Active Sync, there's an option int the configuration of AS that allows wireless connection while the device is docked, I haven't tried but seem that's your answer.

I hope this works for you.

See you.

Comment: Cheers Amedio, that sorted the problem

Comment: I have not tested that, already, but I though it would be the correct solution :)